# О применении слова убирать (убираться)

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Доброго дня, господа знатоки!

Как правильно написать — "убирать дома" или "убираться дома"?

Почему сейчас стало возможным произносить глагол "убирать" с возвратной частицей "-сь" и "-ся"? Разве это не ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

Глаголы с постфиксом *-ся* вовсе не обязательно означают действие, направленное на себя. РГ-80 выделяет 7 лексико-грамматических разрядов таких глаголов, и глаголы с собственно-возвратным значением образуют лишь один из этих разрядов. Глагол *убираться* относится к другому разряду, а именно к глаголам косвенно-возвратного значения (наряду с *укладываться, строиться, построиться, запасаться, устраиваться* и подобными). Таким образом, он образован в полном соответствии с грамматическими нормами русского языка. Словари дают при нём помету *разг.,* однако она указывает лишь на предпочтительную сферу употребления, а никак не на "ошибочность" этого глагола.

Comment: Да, конечно.
Только у Виноградова таких разрядов аж 15.
http://www2.bigpi.biysk.ru/wwwsite/data/typology/011.htm
(твм нумерация сбита, восемь + семь)

Ссылку на РГ-80 не дадите?

Answer (score 2):

Убираться (дома) - разговорная форма, но никак не безграмотная. Фиксируется, например, у [Кузнецова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F).

Извиняться в значении "извините меня, простите" - действительно неправильно. Но в косвенной речи ("Он извинялся, что не смог приехать") вполне уместно.

Возвратная частица в русском языке помимо очевидного значения переноса действия на себя может иметь огромное число значений. Сравните такие глаголы как кусаться, спаться (мне хорошо спалось), красоваться, ругаться...

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю — ошибка. Убраться — это убрать себя. И то, что это "разговорная форма", не отменяет безграмотности в применении. У нас "разговорных форм" развелось...
В следующих выражениях  глагол употреблён правильно (а выражения, согласитесь, весьма разговорные):
*Убирайтесь отсюда подобру-поздорову!

Надо  поскорее убираться, пока не застали на месте преступления.

Убирайся, пока цел!

Убрались восвояси.*

Ещё "убрать себя" прежде значило привести самого себя в порядок, нарядиться. Помните романс "Вишнёвая шаль"?
*"Нарядись, уберись в свой наряд дорогой,

И на плечи накинь шаль с каймой расписной".*

Answer (score 0):

Убирайся! (Уйди с дороги! Пошёл вон! Исчезни!)
В любом другом контексте просто **убираться** требует уточнения: по дому (хотя лучше звучит **прибраться** или **убрать в доме**), уместиться в чём-либо, спрятаться где-либо.

Без такого уточнения **убираться**, а именно **убраться** означает умереть.
 Интересно, что почти во всех словарях слово отмечено стилями ***устар*** и **разг**. Ошибка современников в отказе от требуемого уточнения происходит из-за преобладания телеграфного темпа общения и прохладного отношения к восприятию своей речи или текста.